I tried scraping a website with selenium python and saving it to csv but its printing and duplicating only the first result
I am scraping the top 250 movies on imdb and its giving me only the first mvoive in my dictionary.
The is the code that I wrote
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://m.imdb.com/chart/top/'
driver = webdriver.Edge()
driver.get(url)

title = []
year = []

container = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, './/ul[contains(@role, "presentation")]')

for x in container:
    try:
        title.append(x.find_element(By.XPATH, './/a[contains(@class, "title")]').text)
        year.append(x.find_element(By.XPATH, './/span[contains(@class, "title")]').text)
 except:
    pass
# print(x.text)

df_movie = pd.DataFrame({'title' : title, 'year' : year})
df_movie.to_csv(r'C:\Users\martha\OneDrive\Python\imbd_project.csv', index=False)


Some of your locators were not correct and you need to add waits. The code below has been tested and is working.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://m.imdb.com/chart/top/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

title = []
year = []
runtime = []
rating = []

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
containers = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul.ipc-metadata-list > li")))

for container in containers:
    title.append(container.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'h3').text)
    metadata = container.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.cli-title-metadata > span")
    year.append(metadata[0].text)

df_movie = pd.DataFrame({"title": title, "year": year})
df_movie.to_csv(r'imbd_project.csv', index=False)


I tried this but I'm getting IndexError: list index out of range

Yep... I said I tested only the first 5. Did you debug the issue? What did you find?

The issue is that one movie did not have a rating. You can either test for that or I just removed the last two fields since you didn't have them originally anyway. I updated the code and it's working with all 250 movies now.

Why did you change the accepted answer? When you award it to someone else, it takes it away from mine.

Sorry about that, I'm still getting familiar with this website

.//ul[contains(@role, "presentation")] not movies list section
#container = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, './/ul[contains(@role, "presentation")]')

# change to blow code

movies_section = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, './/ul[contains(@role, "presentation")]')
container = movies_section.find_elements(By.XPATH, './/li[contains(@class, "cli-parent")]')


See the refactored code below:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://m.imdb.com/chart/top/'
driver = webdriver.Edge()
driver.get(url)

title = []
year = []

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
all_title_elements = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//ul[contains(@role, 'presentation')]//li//a//h3")))
all_year_elements = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//ul[contains(@role, 'presentation')]//li//a//h3//following::span[1]")))

for t in all_title_elements:
    title.append(t.text)

for y in all_year_elements:
    year.append(y.text)

df_movie = pd.DataFrame({'title': title, 'year': year})
print(df_movie)
# df_movie.to_csv(r'C:\Users\martha\OneDrive\Python\imbd_project.csv', index=False)

Console output:
                           title  year
0    1. The Shawshank Redemption  1994
1               2. The Godfather  1972
2             3. The Dark Knight  2008
3       4. The Godfather Part II  1974
4                5. 12 Angry Men  1957
..                           ...   ...
245   246. It Happened One Night  1934
246                247. Drishyam  2015
247      248. Dances with Wolves  1990
248      249. Gangs of Wasseypur  2012
249                 250. Aladdin  1992

[250 rows x 2 columns]

Process finished with exit code 0

